# Sqoop - Import Job failed

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to import a table of 32 Million records from SQL Server to Hive via Sqoop. The connection is SQL Server is successful. But Map/Reduce job does not successfully execute. It gives the following error:

```
18/07/19 04:00:11 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
18/07/19 04:00:27 DEBUG db.DBConfiguration: Fetching password from job credentials store
18/07/19 04:00:27 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
18/07/19 04:00:27 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '1=1' and upper bound '1=1'
18/07/19 04:00:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/07/19 04:00:29 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1531917395459_0002
18/07/19 04:00:30 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1531917395459_0002
18/07/19 04:00:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1531917395459_0002/
18/07/19 04:00:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1531917395459_0002
    18/07/19 04:43:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1531917395459_0002 running in uber mode : false
18/07/19 04:43:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/07/19 04:43:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1531917395459_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1531917395459_0002 failed 2 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1531917395459_0002_000002 timed out. Failing the application.
18/07/19 04:43:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
18/07/19 04:43:08 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/07/19 04:43:09 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 2,576.6368 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/07/19 04:43:10 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
18/07/19 04:43:10 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
18/07/19 04:43:10 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

Here are the configuration from yarn-site.xml file

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.dispatcher.exit-on-error</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>List of directories to store localized files in.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/${user.name}/nm-local-dir</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to store container logs.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
     <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
     <value>
        $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
        $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*
     </value>
  </property>

<!-- added by me -->
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>

 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>

 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

At first, the job was stuck when it came to connecting with the resource manager via 0.0.0.0:8032. So I changed the host to 127.0.0.1. Then the execution continued further. But then the above error occurred. Even I have tried executing this job with only 1000 rows, but same error. Also, sometimes the job gets Killed.

Here is my sqoop command

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://system-ip;databaseName=TEST" --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --username user1 --password password --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table "customer_data_1000" --table "customer_data_1000" --split-by Account_Branch_Converted -m 1 --verbose
```

Here is my docker command in case:

```
  docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -p 127.0.0.1:8888:8888 -p 127.0.
```

0.1:7180:7180 -p 127.0.0.1:50070:50070 -i 7c41929668d8 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart

Here is the resource manager log:

```
          2018-07-26 07:18:26,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: Expired:appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 Timed out after 600 secs
        2018-07-26 07:24:03,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: Updating application attempt appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000
        2018-07-26 07:35:46,609 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 State change from LAUNCHED to FINAL_SAVING
        2018-07-26 07:35:49,502 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: Expired:quickstart.cloudera:36003 Timed out after 600 secs
        2018-07-26 07:39:44,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: Deactivating Node quickstart.cloudera:36003 as it is now LOST
        2018-07-26 07:44:39,238 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: quickstart.cloudera:36003 Node Transitioned from RUNNING to LOST
        2018-07-26 07:45:09,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001
        2018-07-26 07:49:43,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: Node not found resyncing quickstart.cloudera:36003
        2018-07-26 07:49:43,916 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001
        2018-07-26 07:49:45,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:49:47,095 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 12 on 8032, call org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB.getApplicationReport from 127.0.0.1:45162 Call#608 Retry#0: output error
        2018-07-26 07:49:47,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: The number of failed attempts is 1. The max attempts is 2
        2018-07-26 07:49:47,887 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 12 on 8032 caught an exception
        java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:265)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:474)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelWrite(Server.java:2621)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$1900(Server.java:134)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Responder.processResponse(Server.java:989)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Responder.doRespond(Server.java:1054)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2141)
        2018-07-26 07:49:49,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Registering app attempt : appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:49:49,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from NEW to SUBMITTED
        2018-07-26 07:49:49,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Cleaning master appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to KILLED
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FSAppAttempt: Completed container: container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 in state: KILLED event:KILL
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,460 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1532588462827_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,550 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host quickstart.cloudera:36003, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:8192, vCores:8> available, release resources=true
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 released container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 on node: host: quickstart.cloudera:36003 #containers=0 available=8192 used=0 with event: KILL
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,580 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Removed node quickstart.cloudera:36003 cluster capacity: <memory:0, vCores:0>
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,580 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Application appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000001 is done. finalState=FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:49:50,581 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1532588462827_0001 requests cleared
        2018-07-26 07:49:51,860 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Added Application Attempt appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 to scheduler from user: root
        2018-07-26 07:49:52,125 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from SUBMITTED to SCHEDULED
        2018-07-26 07:50:04,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: quickstart.cloudera:36003 Node Transitioned from NEW to RUNNING
        2018-07-26 07:50:04,534 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Added node quickstart.cloudera:36003 cluster capacity: <memory:8192, vCores:8>
        2018-07-26 07:50:05,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: received container statuses on node manager register :[container_id { app_attempt_id { application_id { id: 1 cluster_timestamp: 1532588462827 } attemptId: 1 } id: 1 } container_state: C_COMPLETE resource { memory: 2048 virtual_cores: 1 } priority { priority: 0 } diagnostics: "Container Killed by ResourceManager\nContainer killed on request. Exit code is 143\nContainer exited with a non-zero exit code 143\n" container_exit_status: -106 creation_time: 1532588806652]
        2018-07-26 07:50:05,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from node quickstart.cloudera(cmPort: 36003 httpPort: 8042) registered with capability: <memory:8192, vCores:8>, assigned nodeId quickstart.cloudera:36003
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=AM Allocated Container        TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1532588462827_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Assigned container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host quickstart.cloudera:36003, which has 1 containers, <memory:2048, vCores:1> used and <memory:6144, vCores:7> available after allocation
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Sending NMToken for nodeId : quickstart.cloudera:36003 for container : container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Clear node set for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: Storing attempt: AppId: application_1532588462827_0001 AttemptId: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 MasterContainer: Container: [ContainerId: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001, NodeId: quickstart.cloudera:36003, NodeHttpAddress: quickstart.cloudera:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.17.0.2:36003 }, ]
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from SCHEDULED to ALLOCATED_SAVING
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from ALLOCATED_SAVING to ALLOCATED
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Launching masterappattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,027 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Setting up container Container: [ContainerId: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001, NodeId: quickstart.cloudera:36003, NodeHttpAddress: quickstart.cloudera:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.17.0.2:36003 }, ] for AM appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,027 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Command to launch container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 : $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA  -Xmx1024m org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster 1><LOG_DIR>/stdout 2><LOG_DIR>/stderr
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,027 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Create AMRMToken for ApplicationAttempt: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,027 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Creating password for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,128 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Done launching container Container: [ContainerId: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001, NodeId: quickstart.cloudera:36003, NodeHttpAddress: quickstart.cloudera:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.17.0.2:36003 }, ] for AM appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,129 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from ALLOCATED to LAUNCHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:06,953 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:32,951 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 (auth:SIMPLE)
        2018-07-26 07:50:33,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: AM registration appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
emanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:34,887 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:34,893 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED
        2018-07-26 07:50:34,893 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=AM Allocated Container        TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1532588462827_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:34,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Assigned container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 of capacity <memory:1024, vCores:1> on host quickstart.cloudera:36003, which has 2 containers, <memory:3072, vCores:2> used and <memory:5120, vCores:6> available after allocation
        2018-07-26 07:50:36,467 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:36,478 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Sending NMToken for nodeId : quickstart.cloudera:36003 for container : container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:36,479 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED
        2018-07-26 07:50:36,898 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_01_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:38,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
        2018-07-26 07:50:38,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: checking for deactivate...
        2018-07-26 07:50:54,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED
        2018-07-26 07:50:54,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FSAppAttempt: Completed container: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 in state: COMPLETED event:FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:54,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1532588462827_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002
        2018-07-26 07:50:54,555 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 of capacity <memory:1024, vCores:1> on host quickstart.cloudera:36003, which currently has 1 containers, <memory:2048, vCores:1> used and <memory:6144, vCores:7> available, release resources=true
        2018-07-26 07:50:54,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 released container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 on node: host: quickstart.cloudera:36003 #containers=1 available=6144 used=2048 with event: FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:50:55,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 completed with event FINISHED
    438 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FSAppAttempt: Completed container: container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 in state: COMPLETED event:FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,438 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp     RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1532588462827_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,438 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host quickstart.cloudera:36003, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:8192, vCores:8> available, release resources=true
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,438 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: Updating application attempt appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: 0
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from RUNNING to FINAL_SAVING
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: The number of failed attempts is 2. The max attempts is 2
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Updating application application_1532588462827_0001 with final state: FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1532588462827_0001 State change from RUNNING to FINAL_SAVING
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating info for app: application_1532588462827_0001
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Application appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 is done. finalState=FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1532588462827_0001 requests cleared
        2018-07-26 07:51:00,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Cleaning master appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Application application_1532588462827_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 0
        For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1532588462827_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
        Diagnostics: Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1532588462827_0001 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,785 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root     OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager     RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED       PERMISSIONS=Application application_1532588462827_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1532588462827_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 0
        For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1532588462827_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
        Diagnostics: Failing this attempt. Failing the application.     APPID=application_1532588462827_0001
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1532588462827_0001,name=customer_data_1000.jar,user=root,queue=root.root,state=FAILED,trackingUrl=http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/cluster/app/application_1532588462827_0001,appMasterHost=N/A,startTime=1532588804719,finishTime=1532591460451,finalStatus=FAILED
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,821 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000001 completed with event FINISHED
        2018-07-26 07:51:05,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler: Container container_1532588462827_0001_02_000002 completed with event FINISHED
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you also provide ResourceManager log

Comment: I have added ResourceManager log to my question

Comment: Have you been able to run WordCount or another MR job?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a precise solution but what I can do is tell you what the root cause can be:

1. Try to run the Sqoop job as a non-root user.
2. Check if your JDK is properly installed on the host and your JAVA_HOME is set properly.
3. Check if you have granted the right permissions to the Databases you're using.

Your job got failed because of one of the above reasons. As you have enough v-cores and memory available and containers were also being created. So, everything from the processing end was fine, but there must be a configuration error.

Comment: I followed this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo ... create a non-root user .. check java_home and checked the right permissions to the database .. but the job get stuck

Comment: Also, I am unable to track my job. The url does not work http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1531917395459_0002/

Comment: Try entring IP instead the DNS

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Also where to input the IP Address?

Comment: The path where it is written `quickstart.cloudera` because connection refused is maimly when your connection can not resolve your DNS. So try giving IP address